# How to fix "unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'" in graphing population models?

Tags: python

I'm trying to graph Exponential and Logistic Population Models for my Differential Equations subject as part of its requirements, this is my code so far, it gets an error when I run it, what should I replace/do for this to run?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from IPython.display import clear_output

print("Utilize Which Growth Model of Population? (Type A or B)")
print()
print("A Exponential Growth Model")
print("B Logistic Growth Model")
print()
A = int(1)
# Exponential Growth Model
B = int(2)
# Logistic Growth Model
C = input("Growth Model of choice : ")
print()

if C == "A":
    # Definition of Parameters
    print("The Differential Equation of your chosen growth model is P'(t) = r*P(t)")
    print()
    print("Where r = growth parameter")
    print("Where P(t) = total population at a certain time t")
    print("Where t = time")
    print()
    # Explanation of Differential Equation
    print("This equation can be considered as the exponential differential equation")
    print("because its solution is P(t) = P(0)*e^r*t ; where P(0) = Initial Population")
    print()
    print("This equation can be portrayed by using this graph : ")

    # Graph Code
    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-50, 50, 10), np.linspace(-50, 50, 10))
    r = float(input("Encode Growth Parameter :"))
    t = float(input("At how many years do you want to solve? :"))
    P = float(input("Encode Population Count :"))
    P = y
    t = x
    x = np.asarray(x, dtype="float64")
    Un = u / P * (math.exp ** (r * t))
    Vn = u / P * (math.exp ** (r * t))
    plt.quiver(x, y, Un, Vn)
    plt.plot([8, 12, 25, 31], [1, 16, 20, 40])
    plt.show()

if C == "B":
    print("The Differential Equation of your chosen growth model is y' = k*y*(M-y)")
    print()
    print("Where k = slope of the function")
    print("Where y = y-value at the specific point")
    print("Where M = limit of y as x approaches infinity")
    print()
    print("This equation is derived using *** ")
```

I ran this code in python and I expected it to run as I have seen through examples online, but instead I got an "unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'" what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using [`math.exp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.exp) as a number, but it's actually a function: `exp(x)` returns `e` raised to the power of `x`.

see:

```py
In [1]: import math

In [2]: type(math.exp)
Out[2]: builtin_function_or_method

In [3]: math.exp(1)
Out[3]: 2.718281828459045

In [4]: math.exp(2)
Out[4]: 7.38905609893065
```

instead of `math.exp**(r*t)` use `math.exp(r*t)`

Comment: he just assigned `x,y = np.meshgrid (np.linspace(-50, 50, 10), np.linspace(-50, 50, 10))`, and then `t = x`, so `type(t) = numpy.ndarray`. this will potentially throw an error

Comment: I got this error: "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

 x,y = np.meshgrid (np.linspace(-50, 50, 10), np.linspace(-50, 50, 10)) ;
    r = float (input ("Encode Growth Parameter :")) ;
    t = float (input ("At how many years do you want to solve? :")) ;
    P = float (input ("Encode Population Count :")) ;
    P = y ; 
    t = x ;
    x = np.asarray (x, dtype='float64')
    Un = (P/P*(math.exp(r*t)))
    Vn = (P/P*(math.exp(r*t))) 
    plt.quiver (x, y, Un, Vn) ;
    plt.plot ([8, 12, 25, 31], [1, 16, 20, 40]) ;
    plt.show ()

Comment: @JTM take Adam's answer and replace `math` with `np`, as `math.exp()` only accepts one real number as a parameter.